# Asp.Net Core File Upload on AWS ECS/EC2 in Container

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

I have an asp .net core application deployed to AWS in a docker linux container, hosted in ECS into an EC2 server (not fargate). We have a react front-end UI that uploads a file to the .net core api, which we then process. This works properly in dev, however, in prod, the file upload is failing and I think that the server does not have access/rights to save the file to our upload folder (think webapproot/upload).

Do we need to take the file, save it to S3, then process from there? or is this simply a rights issue?

Comment: Have you tried running the docker container locally to see if you have the same issue?

Comment: where is the file upload uploading to?

Comment: Did you get this to work?  Can you share any of the resources/articles that helped you?  I'm using a linux fargat container on aws   and trying to write a file using .net core to a EC2 instance(file share)

Comment: We did get this to work, I will add the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this to work by not saving it in-flight, we kept it as a byte stream until we stored it in the S3 bucket. Note, you'll want to make sure you use `IFormFileCollection` and ensure when you start the app that you include your secrets, and in your CI/CD you tell aws to include secrets from Secrets Manager (assuming you're hosting them there).

Endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(int.MaxValue)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]IFormFileCollection files, [FromForm]FileTypes fileType)
    {
        try
        {
            long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

            var fileName = string.Empty;

            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileName = $"{fileType.ToString()}-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";

                    await _mediator.Send(new S3Messages.Save(formFile.OpenReadStream(), "fileimport", fileName));
                }
            }

            return Ok(new FileUploadResponse
            {
                Count = files.Count,
                Size = size,
                Files = files.Select(f => new ImportFile()
                {
                    Created = DateTime.Now,
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileSize = size,
                    FileTypeID = (int)fileType,
                }),
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
      public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();

                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                    {
                        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                        var secretsJson = Secrets.Get("us-east-1");

                        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(secretsJson);

                        config.AddInMemoryCollection(dict);
                    }
                })
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new ServiceProviderFactory<Program>())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

ci/cd pipeline yaml file, ensure to bring the secrets in when creating the task:

```
- export TASK_VERSION=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --family "${ECS_TASK_NAME}" --network-mode host --execution-role-arn "xxx" --container-definitions "[{\"name\":\"$PROJECT_NAME\",\"image\":\"$IMAGE_NAME\",\"portMappings\":[{\"containerPort\":5000,\"hostPort\":5000,\"protocol\":\"tcp\"}],\"memoryReservation\":512,\"memory\":2004,\"essential\":true,\"environment\":[{\"name\":\"SECRETS_NAME\",\"value\":\"$xxx_SECRETS_NAME\"}],\"secrets\":[{\"name\":\"$xxx_SECRETS_NAME\",\"valueFrom\":\"$xxx_SECRETS\"}]}]" | jq --raw-output '.taskDefinition.revision')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HostingEnvironment

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public VehicleBrandController(ApplicationDbContext context, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _context = context;
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}
```

Remember using Path.Combine, not working if using propagation or plus to concatenate string as path.

```
public async Task UploadBrandImage()
{
    var uploadDir = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images/vehicle-icons");

    //If folder of new key is not exist, create the folder.
    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDir);

    foreach (var contentFile in Request.Form.Files)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images/vehicle-icons", contentFile.FileName);

        if (contentFile.Length <= 0) continue;

        // Using like this will not work
        //await contentFile.CopyToAsync(new FileStream($"{uploadDir}\\{contentFile.FileName}", FileMode.Create));

        using (var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await contentFile.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
        }
    }
}
```